# How to replace column values with results from for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

my dataframe looks something like this:

```
teams    x_in_mins    y_in_mins   z_in_mins
team_a      50            120         24
team_b      80            66          30
team_c      30            90          70
```

I want to convert integer columns (which represent total minutes) to time format (hours & minutes).

For this step i've created a for loop:

```
for column in df[["x_in_mins","y_in_mins","z_in_mins"]]:
    print(pd.to_timedelta(df[column], unit='min'))
```

this iterates over the specified columns, converting integers to timedelta.

How can I then make the for loop results into a new dataframe?

the final dataframe should look like:

```
teams    x_in_hrs    y_in_hrs   z_in_hrs
team_a    00:40:00    02:00:00    00:24:00
team_b    01:20:00    01:06:00    00:30:00
team_c    00:30:00    01:30:00    01:10:00
```

Comment: Shouldn't the team_A  x_in_hrs be 00:50:00 ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `transform`:

```
def foo(col):
    return pd.to_timedelta(col, unit='min').astype(str).str.rsplit().str[-1]

df[["x_in_mins","y_in_mins","z_in_mins"]].transform(foo)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the result be in format of `'hh:mm:ss'` rather than `'0 days hh:mm:ss'` (if you are sure the number of minutes won't be over 24 hours) and also want to rename the column labels from `*_in_mins` to `*_in_hrs`, you can use:

Select columns by [`.filter()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
cols = df.filter(like='in_mins').columns
```

Then, convert minutes to `'hh:mm:ss'`:

```
df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_timedelta(x, unit='min').astype(str).str[-8:])
```

Finally, rename column labels:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('in_mins', 'in_hrs')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

    teams  x_in_hrs  y_in_hrs  z_in_hrs
0  team_a  00:50:00  02:00:00  00:24:00
1  team_b  01:20:00  01:06:00  00:30:00
2  team_c  00:30:00  01:30:00  01:10:00
```